# How to combine results from 2 queries without common "GROUP BY" element

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to count the number of instances of different types and group them by a field denoting location.  However, the location from my second query is obtained by a sub string of yet another field and is 300 less than the desired number.

The goal is to sum phone types by location. For IP phones (`type` 9608, b189, and 9611), the location is determined by the `nr` (network region).  For analog devices (`type` cordless, 2500, and fax) the location is determined by the first 3 characters on the `port`.

I have each individual query working, for the most part, as desired.  I have 2 issues:

1. The `nr` from the second query needs to have 300 added to the result.
2. I have not been able to combine the 2 queries together to obtain the desired, single result.

Example Data Set

```
+------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+------+-----------+------+------+--------+-----------+------+----------------+------+
| id   | extension    | port    | name                        | cp1  | cor  | type      | cp2  | cos  | tenent | prod_id   | tcp  | ip             | nr   |
+------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+------+-----------+------+------+--------+-----------+------+----------------+------+
|   62 | 111-000-0201 | S00215  | Baker Mail Rm               |      |    2 | 9608      |      |    1 |      4 | IP_Phone  | tcp  | 172.20.94.76   | 308  |
|   63 | 111-000-0202 | S00216  | Baker Copy Rm               |      |    2 | 9608      |      |    1 |      4 |           |      |                |      |
|   66 | 111-000-0205 | S00235  | Baker Conference Rm 2       |      |    2 | b189      |      |    1 |      4 | IP_Phone  | tcp  | 172.20.94.22   | 308  |
|  123 | 111-000-0626 | 008V301 | Baker Cordless              |      |    2 | cordless  |      |    1 |      1 |           |      |                |      |
|  145 | 111-000-1200 | S12329  | JEF-MAIN Dental 1           |      |    2 | 9611      |      |    1 |      1 | IP_Phone  | tcp  | 172.20.195.160 | 490  |
|  885 | 999-888-3025 | 190V203 | JEF WP Admin Conf Rm        |      |    2 | 2500      |      |    1 |      1 |           |      |                |      |
|  890 | 999-888-1561 | 190V201 | JEF-GATO Clinic Fax         |      |    2 | fax       |      |    1 |      1 |           |      |                |      |
|  993 | 111-777-0202 | S00256  | Test Rm                     |      |    2 | 9608      |      |    1 |      4 | IP_Phone  |      | 172.20.190.45  | 303  |
|  994 | 111-777-0212 | S00217  | Test Rm  2                  |      |    2 | 9608      |      |    1 |      4 | IP_Phone  |      | 172.20.190.46  | 303  |
```

Query 1

```
SELECT nr, 
        sum(type='9608') '9608', 
        sum(type='9611') '9611', 
        sum(type='b189') 'b189', 
        count(*) 'Total IP' 
FROM station GROUP BY nr;
```

Result 1

```
+------+------+------+------+----------+
| nr   | 9608 | 9611 | b189 | Total IP |
+------+------+------+------+----------+
| 308  |    1 |    0 |   1  |        2 |
| 490  |    0 |    1 |   0  |        1 |
| 303  |    2 |    0 |   0  |        2 |
```

Query 2

```
SELECT SUBSTR(port, 1, 3) AS 'nr', 
        sum(type='fax') 'fax', 
        sum(type='2500') 'analog', 
        sum(type='cordless') 'cordless', 
        count(*) 'Total Analog' 
FROM station 
WHERE port LIKE '___V%' 
GROUP BY SUBSTR(port, 1, 3);
```

Result 2

```
+------+------+--------+----------+--------------+
| nr   | fax  | analog | cordless | Total Analog |
+------+------+--------+----------+--------------+
| 008  |    0 |      0 |        1 |            1 |
| 190  |    1 |      1 |        0 |            2 |
```

The desired result is

```
+------+------+------+------+----------+------+--------+----------+--------------+
| nr   | 9608 | 9611 | b189 | Total IP | fax  | analog | cordless | Total Analog |
+------+------+------+------+----------+------+--------+----------+--------------+
| 308  |    1 |    0 |   1  |        2 |    0 |      0 |        1 |            1 |
| 490  |    0 |    1 |   0  |        1 |    1 |      1 |        0 |            2 |
| 303  |    2 |    0 |   0  |        2 |    0 |      0 |        0 |            0 |
```

Comment: Since you do not have a common group by, you need to describe us the logic to combine the queries.

Comment: @Shadow The logic would be to match the first 3 digits of the `port`, plus 300, from query 2 to the `nr` from query 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need? I used inner join. check my answer.

```
SELECT s1.nr, 
        sum(type='9608') '9608', 
        sum(type='9611') '9611', 
        sum(type='b189') 'b189', 
        count(*) 'Total IP' ,
        fax,
        analog,
        cordless,
        TotalAnalog
FROM station s1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT SUBSTR(port, 1, 3) AS 'nr', 
          sum(type='fax') 'fax', 
          sum(type='2500') 'analog', 
          sum(type='cordless') 'cordless', 
          count(*) 'TotalAnalog' 
  FROM station 
  WHERE port LIKE '___V%' 
  GROUP BY SUBSTR(port, 1, 3)
) as s2
ON s1.nr = s2.nr + 300
GROUP BY nr;
```

working [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da96875/7)

Comment: Thank you @Simonare. This is great however the results do not include results from the 1st query if there are no results from the inner query. If there is no analog, I would want the result to include the info from the 1st query and have zeros for the second.  I added a data row to the Fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for leading me to the correct "rabbit hole.".  All I had to do is change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` to obtain the desired results.